# Avoid file creation with boost::interprocess::message queue

Tags: c++, windows, boost, ipc

I am using `boost::interprocess::message queue` on windows. It creates a file in `C:\program data`. Is there some way i could use a different shared memory than memory mapping like `windows_shared_memory`. I came across [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/7027) but could not find `windows_message_queue` as part of boost.

My use case is that at some point Process `P1` will create a message queue and wait for a message from pocess `P2`. When `P1` receives the message(using `timed_receive()`) the message queue is deleted. This will happen a number of times(with different name).

Is there some other mechanism which i can leverage here. The main concern is avoiding creating files on user's location.

Answer (score 0):

It should be there... have you tried this include?

```
#include <boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp>
```